# Fetching values of a particular field from an array to a variable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In cakephp, I executed this query to find the id field value of the corresponding username

```
$count = $this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('User.username' => $n)))
```

How I will get take the value of a field from this array result to a variable?

I am new to cakephp and any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Well, after calling find, you will notice that $count will be populated if something was brought from the database. I would change something, though, I would use "first" instead of "all" because you are finding only one record.

You can either use this

```
//in your controller
$count = $this->User->find('first', 
    array('conditions'=>array('User.username' => $n)));
//and set the variable to be used in the view in this way
$this->set('yourId', $count['User']['id']);
```

Then in your view

echo $yourId;

Or, you can also do this

```
$yourId = $this->User->field('id', array('User.username' => $n));
$this->set(compact('yourId'));
```

and then in your view

```
echo $yourId
```